# Is it bad practice to have a entity with no distinct attributes?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, entity-relationship

For example. Lets say I have a superclass entity `Super`, then we have its subclass entities `Sub1`and `Sub2` with `disjoint` constraint. `Sub1` also has no attributes. And lets say I want to form a relationship between `Sub1` a new entity `Sub3`.

Is it bad practice to have to keep `Sub1` since it has no distinct attributes? (disregarding the attributes attained from inheritance).

note: `sub1` and `sub2` is split to enforce a constraint such that sub2 has no relation to `sub3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think to have a subclass without attributes is as a placeholder for a future subclass which is not yet designed. The constraint would be that sub2 has no relation to the placeholder, sub1. So when the design is complete, change sub1 to implement that design. The constraint would still hold and you wouldn't have needless complexity in your overall design.